# How to prevent unauthorized computers from accessing a website

Tags: web, security, restrictions

I've developed a web application for a company. Because the company has offices in all the states in the country, the web application will be uploaded to the internet.

Is it possible to restrict access to the web application to only know computers used by the company; maybe by using their `MAC` address?

Or is there an efficient way to limit access to a website to only recognized computers? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, it's called making them login.

Comment: MAC addresses only are used between individual nodes on the internet. They aren't sent the whole way.

Comment: Require VPN access and only serve it on the intranet.

Answer (score 0):

If the company has dedicated IP address pool, you may block access from the computers that are outside of this address pool. Otherwise your best bet would be to authorize the people, who has authority to access your application.

Comment: Thanks @lenik for the answer. Users will need to login before using the web app. But an attacker can still attempt to crack user passwords. Is the "authorize people" as your best bet a different method from the usual form login?

Comment: "authorize the people" generally means plain old login, however you may use contemporary forms, like `OAuth2` to ease the burden of storing passwords and dealing with all user security data.